# ListView Row Layout Pushing ImageButton Off Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to create a Row layout to use in my ListView, 
but when the text is too long, it pushes the right hand side ImageButton off the screen.
I want the text to just continue on the next line without interfering with the ImageButton-

**This is the layout I have so far, I tried adding weight properties to set how much space could be use but I couldn't get it to work.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Text3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ImageButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank You.

Comment: use weights to define how much each view should take size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what lenght if text, first and last image will be of width 50dp occupied, rest space for text.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I was using the weight property incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You're using too many LinearLayouts, and also you're not defining any constrain for your views space.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ImageButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ImageView"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```